# Gradle 7: how to get list of implementation dependencies (including sub) in a task?

Tags: gradle

I need to have full list of dependencies necessary to run a project (so subdependencies are also important!).

```
task generateLibsDescriptor() {
  doFirst {
    configurations.compileClasspath.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {
      println it
    }
  }
}
```

This code works, but there are also `compileOnly` dependencies listed. I tried to change `compileClasspath` to `implementation`, but had an error `Resolving dependency configuration 'implementation' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.`

Is it possible to have a list of just `implementation` dependencies (with subdependencies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration `compileClasspath` extends `compileOnly` and `implementation`. New config should be created which extends only `implementation` but resolvable.

```
configurations {
        resolvableImpl.extendsFrom(implementation)
        resolvableImpl.canBeResolved(true)
}

task generateLibsDescriptor() {
  doFirst {
    configurations.resolvableImpl.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {
      println it
    }
  }
}
```